# How to make all divs the same width as their narrowset sibling

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How do I make all divs the same width as its narrowest sibling.

Eg: I have a:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">Hello</div>
  <div class="div2">Hello this s some text</div>
</div>
```

Here I want to make the `div2` element the same width as its narrowest sibling (`div1`) without changing the HTML part.

Comment: and you want to do it without changeing the class of div1 to div 2 ?

Comment: are those div side by side or on top of each others?. Your question is unclear about that :) ... is there only 2 of them ...

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I have them in default (top-to-bottom) manner, and at-least 5-6 of them, but including them is out of the scope.

Comment: okay, is this something alike : https://jsfiddle.net/uykar2cb/ you try to do ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply the css style only to the elements that have "div" keyword in their classname like "div1","div23" or "super_div" and which are child of "wrapper" class then you can use this css selector.

```
.wrapper [class*="div"] {
  width="100%"
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div">Hello</div>
    <div class="div">Hello this s some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this CSS:

```css
.div1 {
    width: 100%;
}
.div2 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div1">Hello</div>
    <div class="div2">Hello this s some text</div>
</div>
```